# Querying a Riak DB by a Subkey

Tags: node.js, riak, riak-js

I'm using riak-js and node.js

If I have a document as follows:

```
 { 'skey1': 'val1',
   'skey2': 'val2',
     ......,
   'skeyn': 'valn'
  }
```

How can I return a document that has skey2 = 'val2'?  How would this be done in node.js / riak-js?

Answer (score 1):

If your storage backend is riak_kv_eleveldb_backend, you can use secondary indexing.

`db.save('airlines', 'KLM', {country: 'NL', established: 1919}, {index: {country: 'NL', established: 1919}});`

and query like

`db.query('airlines', {country: 'NL'});`

(the above snippets shamelessly stolen from [riak-js.org](http://riak-js.org/)